# Search specific word in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have String in mysql Db like as below

```
"Good Mayer Brown Corporate & Securities"
"Three Mayer Brown Good & Securities"
"Three Mayer Brown Corporate & Good"
"Three Mayer Brown Goodies & Securities"
```

I need to find the exact word not like as `LIKE %%` Keyword. Here is the example,

I need to select rows with `"Good"` key Word. This will be select the first 3 rows. last one have the extra words like `"ies"`  Here is my expected result

```
    "Good Mayer Brown Corporate & Securities"
    "Three Mayer Brown Good & Securities"
    "Three Mayer Brown Corporate & Good"
```

I already tried the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myword LIKE '% Good %'  OR myword LIKE 'Good%' OR myword LIKE '% Good'
```

But this is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myword REGEXP '^.*GOOD.*$
```

You can use `REGEXP` to do this.Or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myword REGEXP '[[:<:]]GOOD[[:>:]]'
```

Use with `word boundary`.See demo. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b9d/6/0

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yeah actually.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **[Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)**, which is meant for this kind of search in an optimized way with tons of features, instead of doing like wild card which is slow and even with indexed column using `%%` makes no effect of index. If you do not know how to do it see the manual. And here is a sample example for you

```
mysql> create table test (search varchar(200),fulltext key(search)) engine=myisam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('Good Mayer Brown Corporate & Securities'),('Three Mayer Brown Good & Securities'),('Three Mayer Brown Corporate & Good'),('Three Mayer Brown Goodies & Securities');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test where match(search) against ('good' in boolean mode); 
+-----------------------------------------+
| search                                  |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Good Mayer Brown Corporate & Securities |
| Three Mayer Brown Good & Securities     |
| Three Mayer Brown Corporate & Good      |
+-----------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```